# Spring Security : redirect to previous page after login

Tags: spring, security, redirect, authentication

I want to redirect to previous page after user login always.

I know that redirect to previous page after login when user denied accessing some page.

But I wonder that all that times, if user directly login after click login link or I redirect login page by force.

When the time that I menthion situation above, redirect to index page after login always.

Please help me......